# (meteor)Markdown rendered will overflow-x

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, markdown

```
<div class="col-xs-12" >
  {{#markdown}}{{content}}{{/markdown}}
</div>
```

I am working on a project and this is my problem.

When I render the content brought from database (which was obviously written in markdown),

If the text is long without br, it will overflow x.

I want it to be wrapped inside the container parent, but I am seeing no success.

Has anyone succeeded in this?

Also, is there a link I can refer to so that I can style {{#markdown}} parser?

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTadC.jpg

Here is the screenshot

Comment: I think using `<div class="col-xs-12" style="word-wrap: break-word;">` will work, but this might break other things (I don't know) :/

Comment: Can you re-produce issue in http://meteorpad.com/? we might able to help you then ?

Comment: @Peppe L-G Thanks for the solution! It worked perfectly. I didn't know there was such a simple CSS class for this! I will use it and use it again.